# "No database selected" just in the second and following queries - PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a weird error, I can execute `mysql_query()` just one time. When I execute the following queries I get `No database selected`.

The point is, first query always is executed (`insertar()`) but the following queries fail (`consultar()`) saying that there is not a database selected.
I've rewrited the code to use MyQSLi instead, but curiously, the first query always works again and the following queries just fail with this error: `Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'`.
I've also tried to remove the `insert` and just execute the both `selects` and guess what, just the first `select` is being executed, the next fails.

Note: I know I'm not returning anything from `consultar()`, the error is not there, it's triggered before to reach that statement.

This is the code where I call functions `queries.php`:

```
insertar($nombre, $respuestas, $fallos, $tiempoTotal);

$puntuacionesTiempo = consultar("tiempo");
$puntuacionesFallos = consultar("fallos");
```

This is my `model.php`:

```
<?php 

function conectar(){

    $data = include_once('configDB.php');
    $c = mysql_connect($data["server"], $data["user"], $data["pass"]);
    mysql_select_db("mysql", $c);

    if ($c)
        return $c;
    else
        exit("fail");
}

function insertar($nombre, $resultados, $tiempo){

    $conexion = conectar();

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO juegopreguntas (nombre, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, tiempo) VALUES 
('".$nombre."',".$resultados[0].",".$resultados[1].",".$resultados[2].",".$resultados[3]
.",".$resultados[4].",'".$tiempo."')";

    $conexion->query($consulta);

    cerrarConexion($conexion);

}

function consultar($filtro){

    $conexion = conectar();

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM juegopreguntas ORDER BY tiempo LIMIT 5";

    $re = mysql_query($consulta, $conexion);

    if(!$re)
        echo "Hubo un fallo al consultar -> ".mysql_error();

    cerrarConexion($conexion);
}

function cerrarConexion($conexion){

    mysql_close($conexion);
}
?>
```

Comment: include_once inside a function prevents you from creating a new connection and the old connection gets deleted once you leave that scope.

Comment: I would include your database connection at the top of the file, then use global to reference your globally scoped connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

    $data = include_once('configDB.php');
    $conexion  = mysql_connect($data["server"], $data["user"], $data["pass"]);
    mysql_select_db("mysql", $c);

    if ($c)
        return $c;
    else
        exit("fail");


function insertar($nombre, $resultados, $tiempo){

    global $conexion;

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO juegopreguntas (nombre, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, tiempo) VALUES 
('".$nombre."',".$resultados[0].",".$resultados[1].",".$resultados[2].",".$resultados[3]
.",".$resultados[4].",'".$tiempo."')";

    $conexion->query($consulta);

    cerrarConexion($conexion);

}

function consultar($filtro){

      global $conexion;

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM juegopreguntas ORDER BY tiempo LIMIT 5";

    $re = mysql_query($consulta, $conexion);

    if(!$re)
        echo "Hubo un fallo al consultar -> ".mysql_error();

    cerrarConexion($conexion);
}

function cerrarConexion($conexion){

    mysql_close($conexion);
}
?>
```

Comment: i'll explain in a sec